# Haskell Monad equivalent

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, haskell-platform, option-type

Are both functions equivalent if we choose them at `monadPlusSDif`, `Maybe` as the data type for `MonadPlus`?

```
tdif :: Int -> Int -> Maybe Int
tdif x y
    | y == 0 = Nothing
    | otherwise = Just (div x y)

monadPlusSDif :: MonadPlus m => Int -> Int -> m Int
monadPlusSDif x y = guard (y /= 0) >> return (div x y)
```

Comment: In the future please take the time to type your code into the Stackoverflow editor, images of code are not considerate to others who want to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These functions will have equivalent behavior if `m ~ Maybe`, but their compiled byte-code representation will likely be different.  You could also implement it with actual guards for general `MonadPlus` monads as

```
monadPlusSDif :: MonadPlus m => Int -> Int -> m Int
monadPlusSDif x y
    | y == 0 = mzero
    | otherwise = return $ x `div` y
```

Then you could use it as

```
bigEquation :: Int -> Int -> Maybe Int
bigEquation x y = do
    z1 <- monadPlusSDif x y
    z2 <- monadPlusSDif (x + y) (x - y)
    z3 <- monadPlusSDif y x
    return $ z1 + z2 * z3
```

and the compiler would be able to figure out that in that context, it should use `Maybe` for `m`.

Answer (score 9):

Well, for `Maybe` the `MonadPlus` instance is

```
instance MonadPlus Maybe where
  mempty = Nothing
```

and `guard` is implemented as

```
guard b = if b then return () else mempty
--      = if b then Just   () else Nothing
```

With that knowledge, you can use equational reasoning to deduce that, when `m` is `Maybe`, you can replace the original code

```
monadPlusSDif x y = guard (y /= 0) >> return (div x y)
```

with

```
monadPlusSDif x y = (if y /= 0
  then Just ()
  else Nothing) >> Just (div x y)
```

or

```
monadPlusSDif x y
  | y /= 0    = Just () >>= \_ -> Just (div x y)
  | otherwise = Nothing >>= \_ -> Just (div x y)
```

or

```
monadPlusSDif x y
  | y /= 0    = Just (div x y)
  | otherwise = Nothing
```

or

```
monadPlusSDif x y
  | y == 0    = Nothing
  | otherwise = Just (div x y)
```

so you see that the functions are identical.